# export in csv when for each in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, export-to-csv

I m starting with Powershell and i dont arrive to export in csv with my loop foreach.

With help i have a fonctionnal script without export csv :(

```
$computers= Get-ADComputer -Filter  * -Properties * | Select Description  
foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    if ($computer.Description -ne $null)
    {
        $descriptions = $computer.Description -split "\(" 
        # Write-Host $descriptions
        $accountname = $descriptions[0]
        $pcinfos = $descriptions[1] -split ";"
        $serial = $pcinfos[0]
        Write-Host "$accountname;$serial" 
    }
}

#| Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter "," -Path "**********\exportaddesciption.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Can you help me please ?

Thks

Comment: You definitely want to use `-Properties Description` instead of `-Properties *`, your Domain Controllers will thank you for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` cmdlets, and make sure you create an *object* with two properties instead of attempting to construct the CSV row manually:

```
$computers |Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Description) } |ForEach-Object { 
    $descriptions = $computer.Description -split "\(" 
    $accountname = $descriptions[0]
    $pcinfos = $descriptions[1] -split ";"
    $serial = $pcinfos[0]

    [pscustomobject]@{
        AccountName = $accountname
        Serial      = $serial
    }
} |Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -Path "**********\exportaddesciption.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You are too fast ^^ :D

Comment: @dcaz Practice is the only way to mastery ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems.
Your answer will be like the following. I took the liberty of making your code like I learned reading and asking here.
Good luck!

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter  * -Properties * | Select-Object Description

$result = $computers | ForEach-Object {
    if ($null -ne $computer.Description) {
        $descriptions = $computer.Description -split "\(" 
        # Write-Host $descriptions
        $accountname = $descriptions[0]
        $pcinfos = $descriptions[1] -split ";"
        $serial = $pcinfos[0]
        Write-Host "$accountname;$serial" 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = (Enter what you want to export here with variable name)
        }
    }
}
$result | Export-Csv (Path to report in quotes) -NoTypeInformation
```

Look carefully at the other answer you get some expanded answers I did not provide.